# Adding a conditional column to a panda's multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, multi-index

I have the below multi-index dataframe and am struggling to add a conditional column to the dataframe. My current code generates the error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1
```

The dataframe is below:

```
       ed12 comdty              xau curncy             
           PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D    PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D
date                                                       
1997-10-06       93.75      93.2863     332.55       339.45
1997-10-07       93.78      93.2881     331.45       339.27
1997-10-08       93.65      93.2892     333.25       339.09
1997-10-09       93.64      93.2904     327.75       338.90
1997-10-10       93.59      93.2913     329.65       338.74
```

And I am trying to add a third column for each of ed12 comdty and xau curncy indices called "BREADTH" which is a 1 or 0 depending on whether the PX_LAST column for that index is >= MOV_AVG_200D.

Code below:

```
for ticker in data.columns.levels[0]:

data[(ticker,'BREADTH')] = data.where(data[(ticker,'PX_LAST')]>=data[(ticker,'MOV_AVG_200D')],1,0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about `data[(ticker,'BREADTH')] = np.where(data[(ticker,'PX_LAST')]>=data[(ticker,'MOV_AVG_200D')],1,0)` ?

Comment: `data` was changed to `np` (need first `import numpy as np`)

Comment: that worked like a charm - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpliest is convert boolean mask to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
import pandas as pd

for ticker in data.columns.levels[0]:
    mask = data[(ticker,'PX_LAST')]>=data[(ticker,'MOV_AVG_200D')]
    data[(ticker,'BREADTH')] = mask.astype(int)

data = data.sort_index(axis=1,ascending=[True, False])
print (data)
           ed12 comdty                      xau curncy                     
               PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D BREADTH    PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D BREADTH
date                                                                       
1997-10-06       93.75      93.2863       1     332.55       339.45       0
1997-10-07       93.78      93.2881       1     331.45       339.27       0
1997-10-08       93.65      93.2892       1     333.25       339.09       0
1997-10-09       93.64      93.2904       1     327.75       338.90       0
1997-10-10       93.59      93.2913       1     329.65       338.74       0
```

---

Or use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for reshape, add column with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) of booelan mask and then reshape back by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) + [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
data = data.stack(level=0)
data['BREADTH'] = (data['PX_LAST'] >= data['MOV_AVG_200D']).astype(int)
data = data.unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
print (data)
           ed12 comdty                      xau curncy                     
               PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D BREADTH    PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D BREADTH
date                                                                       
1997-10-06       93.75      93.2863       1     332.55       339.45       0
1997-10-07       93.78      93.2881       1     331.45       339.27       0
1997-10-08       93.65      93.2892       1     333.25       339.09       0
1997-10-09       93.64      93.2904       1     327.75       338.90       0
1997-10-10       93.59      93.2913       1     329.65       338.74       0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only these 4 columns, you can just insert the 2 BREADTH columns like below:

```
df.insert(2,('ed12 comdty','BREADTH'),(df.iloc[:,0] > df.iloc[:,1]).astype(int))

df.insert(len(df.columns),('xau curncy','BREADTH'),(df.iloc[:,-2] > df.iloc[:,-1]).astype(int))

df
Out[1495]: 
           ed12 comdty                      xau curncy                     
               PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D BREADTH    PX_LAST MOV_AVG_200D BREADTH
Date                                                                       
1997-10-06       93.75      93.2863       1     332.55       339.45       0
1997-10-07       93.78      93.2881       1     331.45       339.27       0
1997-10-08       93.65      93.2892       1     333.25       339.09       0
1997-10-09       93.64      93.2904       1     327.75       338.90       0
1997-10-10       93.59      93.2913       1     329.65       338.74       0
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually might have more than 4 columns eventually but this was also useful